# Reactjs json looping image path not loading

Tags: json, reactjs

I am new to reactjs - I am keen to retain all the content from json - but I am having an issue with the images.

So the json looks like this:

```
"items" : [
    {
        "title" : "Projekt ausschreiben",
        "description" : "Schreiben Sie Ihr Projekt aus und zeigen Sie es einer handverlesenen Gruppe von Fachexperten",
        "image" : "/img/home/works_emp_01.png"
    },
    {
        "title" : "15 Minuten Video-Gespräch",
        "description" : "Führen Sie eine unverbindliche Unterhaltung mit 3 vorselektierten Anwälten",
        "image" : "/img/home/works_emp_02.png"
    },
    {
      "title" : "Transparente Zusammenarbeit",
      "description" : "Erhalten Sie einen bindenden Kostenvoranschlag und arbeiten Sie online zusammen",
      "image" : "/img/home/works_emp_03.png"
    }
]
```

and then I've tried to loop through the markup on the template like this.

In a previous research it was suggested to use a require.context function to get the image paths defined. - but this isn't working

```
const pathToImages = require.context('./src', true)
    {
       lang.howTiles[0].items.map(function (item, index) {
          return (
              <div key={index}>
                <div className='small-60 columns grid__row--offset--30 show-for-small-only'>&nbsp;</div>
                <div className='small-45 medium-20 small-centered medium-uncentered columns'>
                  <div className='row'>
                    <div className='small-60 medium-45 small-centered columns'>
                      <div className='relative-container'>
                        x<img src={pathToImages(imagesArray[index], true)} />x
                        <img className='centered' src={imagesArray[index]} style={{maxWidth: '50%', marginLeft: '25%'}} />
                        <h3 className='text--bold text--center' style={{marginTop: '25px'}}>{item.title}</h3>
                        <p className='text--center text--font-size-14' style={{marginTop: '15px'}}>{item.description}</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            )
          })
     }
```

Comment: it should be `src={item.image}` to access the image value from the each object of the array.

Comment: well - its not working even if I replace that

Comment: that means there is some issue with path, make sure the image exist at the specified path, whats the meaning of `"/img/home/works_emp_03.png"` it should be `"./img/home/works_emp_03.png"` it should start with either `.` or `..`

Comment: "Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "./src""

Comment: really I just need the json to hold the path -- and for the img src to render a data blob version of it -- but src={require('image/path')} only appears to work on hard coded values

Comment: have you tried this: `src={require(item.image)}`

Comment: yes it doesn't work --

Comment: src={require("../..//img/home/works_emp_02.png")} -- works src={require(item.image)} does not

Comment: because both the paths are different path that you are hardcoding is **../..//img/home/works_emp_02.png** and path that is present in json is **"/img/home/works_emp_03.png"**

Answer (score 0):

check if yours src={ "../your_path_to_image" } works as expected at all.

then check lang.howTiles[0].items for same values. 100% something lost in translation here.

anyway i dont get why ya use require.context('./src', true) ?? it just loads images separate from div src

..maybe helpfull   https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/517

Comment: I am unable to load the images from using json data -- if I loop through the json data replacing text is ok, but pushing a path as a require fails. I was told require.context was a way of replacing this -- take a look at sag's answer -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44045914/reactjs-image-import-dynamically-from-json/44046027?noredirect=1#comment75118663_44046027

Answer (score 0):

make simple array with your image paths and in render function just one div with map and src={item} to check 100% if it path problem or more .. i still got strong feeling of that is problem.

btw. in mentioned older thread there already shows up some problems with this approach.

and i still see no reason to use require.context there if ya simply want add dynamic path to view render.

as i understand `web pack`s require` it runs per build and do all magic paths related job etc.. but it will run in trouble when dynamic path names given

gaearon commented on Mar 10
Is there a problem with explicitly importing them in the code? After all require.context is just sugar for doing that.

here is my code example how to deal with dynamic paths:

var some_path = ( some_value ) ? `${root_path}/0${other_value + tag.toUpperCase()}_Active.svg` : default_path;

```
    return <div className={class_names.join(' ')} >
        <div className="some class name">
            <img src={some_path} alt="image" />
        </div>
    </div>;
```

and with array

```
    return (
        <div className="class name">
            {my_array.map(function( path ){
                return  <img src={ path } alt="image" />
            })}
        </div>
    );
```

Comment: It doesn't work with json data -- with the path coming from that -- -- that bottom example does render -- but it doesn't require the image as a data blob -- there was a problem when this got pushed to server --